# Handling a QTextEdit from another form

Tags: c++, qt

So the question is how do I set a value of textEdit from another form?

Answer (score 1):

You have two options, either you can simply call one of the `setText` functions from a function within another form like this:

`otherForm->setPlainText(text);`

Or you could connect the two forms with signals like this:

```
connect(form1, SIGNAL(updateText(const QString&)),
        form2->myTextEdit, SLOT(setText(const QString&)))
```

Either of these are valid ways to do it.

Answer (score 0):

[`myTextEdit->setPlainText(text)`](http://doc.trolltech.com/4.5/qtextedit.html#setPlainText), [`myTextEdit->setHtml(text)`](http://doc.trolltech.com/4.5/qtextedit.html#setHtml) or by directly modifying the editor's `QTextDocument` instance.

Comment: I have two forms.In a slot of the MainWindow i call QDialog constructor(for example) on which i have QTextEdit, and i want to set its value from the slot of the first form...

Comment: Really i want to set textEdit's value from QSqlRecord, that i have in slot.